# std::get fails when given tuple of 6 ints

Tags: c++, get, tuples

I am using std::get on a tuple. When given a tuple of 5 ints it functions fine:

`typedef std::tuple<int, int, int, int, int> int5Tuple;`

`std::get<1>(int5Tuple(1, 2, 3, 4, 5));`

However on a tuple of 6 ints it fails:

`typedef std::tuple<int, int, int, int, int, int> int6Tuple;`

`std::get<1>(int6Tuple(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6));`

Giving this error: error C2243: 'type cast' : conversion from 'std::tuple<,_V0_t,_V1_t,_V2_t,_V3_t,_V4_t> *' to 'std::tuple<,_V0_t,_V1_t,_V2_t,_V3_t> &&' exists, but is inaccessible.

When searching for a solution, it seemed to suggest that it had something to do with access protection, but I don't think this will be the route to solution.

The intellisense error I got was that no instance of std::get matched the argument list.

Comment: What compiler are you using? Visual Studio?

Comment: Visual studio 2012 edition

Comment: Yup, this explains things. Visual studio has bad c++11 support. Or better saying bad c++ support.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Visual Studio has no real support for variadic templates until VS 2013, which means that they instead use macro-generated "overloads" to support C++11 STL-Features which would normally implemented with this language feature. By default these overloads support up to five (template) arguments. But, at the cost of higher compile times, this can be configured with the `_VARIADIC_MAX` define.

> You can define `_VARIADIC_MAX` project-wide between 5 and 10 inclusive (it defaults to 5).

See the section "Faux variadics" in the [C++11 Features in Visual C++ 11](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vcblog/archive/2011/09/12/10209291.aspx) VCBlog entry for more details.

Answer (score 0):

Visual Studio doesn't have full support of C++11 so it uses a limited amount of template arguments (5 in this case) as compensation for a lack of variadic template support. My assumption is that any template arguments greater than 5 won't compile.